# LINQ to XML GetDefaultNamespace() returns null

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to get the namespace from metadata in this xml document using XDocument:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf=8"?>
<package xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <id>NugetName</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>company</authors>
    <owners>company</owners>
  </metadata>
  <files>
  ...
  </files>
</package>
```

I've tried to use the GetDefaultNamespace() method from XElement like so:

```
XNamespace ns = xmlDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
```

However I get a null value.  I read a few comments that say that because the root namespace has multiple namespaces, it might not be possible to get the namespace of metadata using this method.

I thought to try just grabbing the Attribute from Root.Element("metadata") but because I don't have the namespace that wouldn't work I think.

Any ideas?

PS the reason I won't necessarily know the namespace is because i'm consuming trusted nuspec files and i'm concerned the schema may change.

Comment: How do you get xmlDoc?

Comment: You should not be concerned that it may change; the point of namespaces is to be a _stable_ identifier.  It would only change if the format changes (in which case your code would break).

Comment: XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xml);  the file pointer xml is a copy of the above xml.

Comment: @SLaks My concern arose from the uri having a month year in the uri.  If it's unlikely that it will change i guess i'm doing extra work for little gain.  Was trying to future proof but maybe i'm going overboard.

Comment: No; you're actively trying to defeat the purposes of namespaces.  Don't do that.  The date is the date that the format was created.

Comment: @SLaks Ok; thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xmlDoc.Root` is the `<package>` element.
It has no default namespace.

You want `xmlDoc.Root.Elements().First().GetDefaultNamespace()`.

Comment: Is this with using System.Xml.Linq?